# ServiceStack.Examples Build FAIL all over the place on initial pull/clone from GitHub

Tags: servicestack

this is EXTREMELY frustrating to anyone who just wants to pull down your code and check it out and get it to simple build successfully.

Here's the scoop.

So I open the `ServiceStack.Examples-master\src\AppHarbor.sln` after pulling it from github and **cloning it to my local drive**.

I have had nothing but trouble from the get go.  I have had to fix this solution and project reference as well as assembly references.

there's nothing more irritating to a developer no matter if it's an internal solution or set of .NET projects or external, that bomb during initial build.  This stuff should be building period.

Also when I can't even download an examples solution and get it to build it makes people wonder how well this open source API really is, can I truly even rely on it?  This reflects on you Service Stack.

here's is what I did, nothing out of the norm here:

**1)** Cloned ServiceStack.Examples to my local c:\www\Sandbox folder where I keep stuff I'm playing around with

**2)** Just looking at the folder structure from the start, it makes no sense in terms of being discoverable and more importantly organized.  For example why is there yet another ServiceStack.Examples inside src and then outside of that a ton of other example folders of other example apps in the root of \src also???  So you have stuff in src\ and in src\ServiceStack.Examples, this is hell confusing and disorganized.

ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Examples

**3)** Opened C:\www\Sandbox\ServiceStack.Examples\src\AppHarbor.sln

**4)** Tried to build all, and the first major problem is the MovieRest project doesn't load.  I get an error while opening the .sln that it failed to load it:

ok fine, this is still ridiculous, nobody who downloads a solution should need to worry about fixin this but of course I did, so I readded it because in actuality this .csproj was moved into the src\ServiceStack.MovieRest\Web\ folder and looks to me like nobody even reopened the solution to fix it??

**5)** So then I go to try and build the solution again, notice all the missing binary references in MovieRest.  So ultimately I figured ok, looks like pretty much every other project is getting their references from their associated packages folder however for some Reason MovieRest and the Nortwind projects don't have anything in their packages folder.  so I end up manuall opening up the MovieRest VS 2012 solution and building it, and I guess Nuget must run or something during that build?  Because now walla, I see the missing assemblies pop into ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.MovieRest\packages finally.

**6)** Ok, so I rebuild again, and now it's complaining about missing sqllite assemblies and also a sqllite3.exe.  So now I have to hunt around again to find them for the x84 and x64 and copy those missing assmblies back into ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.MovieRest\Web\sqlite and I also noticed that MoviewRest project was referencing sqllite3.dll in the root of the project which was also missing...this is such a mess.

**7)** I notice that the Northwind project doesn't build either

I don't know what is going on here, I mean is the build really that messed up?  Has to be.

Who is gonna fix this on the ServiceStack end?  how the heck do I get this to finally build and how has this not been reported?

**UPDATED 9/23**

Here are the errors I get after pulling down the "fixed" solution.  I did a Shift + Ctrl + B on it (Build All).  Let me know if I am just missing something here but it's not building yet at least on my side:

[image]

**UPDATE 10/1**

Ok again lets talk about this.

1. I pulled this zip down: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/archive/v3-snapshot.zip  from this page: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/releases
2. Opened the solution src\ServiceStack.sln (VS 2012 version)
3. First I get this SQL Express Error after opening it for the first time:

[image]

4. Now I try to build all on the solution and I get this build error:

[image]

So tell me what I could possibly doing wrong?  This is a "Release" right?  It should build right?  It's not rocket science so how can people say this is a "dev consumer" issue?  All I want is a stable release build.  Simple.

Comment: why the -1, I want to know how we can get this problem resolved.  We shouldn't have these kinds of issues when initially pulling down a solution like this.  I'm having to readd a ton of references and I've decided to place all assemblies into src\lib and just readding them from there.  Unless I'm doing this wrong, do we need to nuget a bunch of stuff?  It's not clear.  Maybe I don't need to manually readd these broken refs and nuget more stuff down?  docs are not clear on that if that's the case.

Comment: I don't know about the negative vote, but if you download correctly the source, then the build  is easy. that's from my experience as a simple user like you.

Comment: All i did was fork the entire example solution from github and download it so not sure why anything would have broken references innthe projects but they do and that solution does not compile.  I also see a ton of repeat dlls in folders outside the nuget package folders and outside src\lib such as that rest solution has a bunch of dlls even in the root of the web project folder which makes ni sense...

Comment: Have you looked at `build.cmd` in the root of the repository?

Comment: look at my updated response.

Comment: build.cmd has nothing to do with it. Which I wonder why would anyone use MSBuild, it's horrible.  Just use Git..anyway...

Comment: wtf do you mean "as a simple user like you".  What's simple is that ANY dev should be able to download the solution and BUILD.  There's nothing that is rocket science behind this and I did what any developer does, the only thing you should have to do which is a Build All command in VS and it should build 100% successfully every time.

Comment: Rather than raising a ruckus complaining about it, and since you've forked the repo already, why don't you fix it and send a pull request? I know that the whole idea that "somebody else needs to fix this" is one of the reasons ServiceStack is going commercial in the next version.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I've started reading through your comments and questions and am appalled by their presumptuousness, negativity and rudeness. It's also clear you're not taking the time to read thru docs as some Q's are already clearly explained. OSS is a courtesy, only thing you're entitled to is what you've created. The ideal OSS-etiquette would've been to fix the build and send a pull-req, failing that a "SS.Examples is broken, pls fix" would've sufficed. You show a surprising level of arrogance for someone seeking help to learn new tech, either ask clear polite q's or learn to help yourself.

Comment: Being completely new how would I infer that i could just fix this.  I figured Stack guys own and maintain this and nowhere in the docs does it say hey feel free to fix our stuff.  Plus i would not know the right way since there are so many broken parts, versioning of assemblies going on here, etc.  sure i could hack a fix now you say i should have known to just do ad you state but who knows if i would be sticking with the right convention you have set up.  Don't you guys have CI in place for servicestack code on github?

Comment: I've voted to close this as it is unlikely to be useful to anybody in the future. The question is too broad; debugging a specific build environment (including 3 full pages of screen shots and complaints) is not going to help future visitors. Glad that the problem was resolved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just upgraded [ServiceStack.Examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples) to VS 2013/IIS Express and updated it to the latest version of ServiceStack v3.9.63 that was just deployed. It should all build now, also some examples requires redis to be running on localhost.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict ok yeah, someone added `packages` to .gitignore for some reason, I've removed it and added all the NuGet packages and tested it out on a clean fork - should all build now.

Comment: what is your guys convention.  So you bring it down then what, go to each project folder and perform an Install-Pakcage ServcieStack on it to bring down all packages?  How is this all automated via NuGet, do I have to do to that effort or am I missing something in how you do your builds here?

Comment: ok thanks, will try again.  That's probably why originally the MovieRest and Northwind was missing packages from one item in my rant above.

Comment: have you considered getting CI on all this stuff?

Comment: Our CI servers is only for the libs/NuGet pkgs, none of the examples atm. SS code-base is still being [heavily re-factored/re-organized for v4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/compare/v3...master) atm, after v4 is released we'll look at adding builds for the example/UseCase projects as well.

Comment: just confirmed today that it indeed is building after your refactoring and after removing that filtering out of packages in Git.  So thanks.

Comment: I do have to tell you that I really wanted to use your framework.  But the fact of the matter is, now my boss has lost confidence from day 1 in that we couldn't just pull down a working build.  That's pretty bad honestly in any environment.  You need to have CI in place.  Otherwise you are giving people a negative view of your API.  It's that simple and it's that powerful.  A working build is critical, or at least CI in place so you know that the person running the Open Source project CARES.  It's like anything, the first impression matters...regardless if the code looks good.

Comment: I also told my boss I have no idea now that this code even works.  If we can't even get a working build at any time, how do I know it even works!  I mean the point is there's no confidence in this framework when it's hosted and maintained in this fashion no matter if you've had other consumers be successful with it.  A release should build and there should be a clear distinction between what builds are what, what's new, what shouldn't be touched, remove the old, yada yada.  I'm just frustrated because now I probably won't be able to leverage SS again and I don't blame my boss's concerns.

Comment: Also, Mythz, please take this as constructive criticism, I'm sure I'm not alone on this feeling with your framework.  I'm trying to give you feedback here and I think the majority of the devs out there would feel the same.  I'm trying to help your cause here and improve your project and that starts with caring about the builds and organization and continual fostering of your documentation.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict As I told you before CI is already in place for both `master` and `v3`, all builds are working and all tests are now passing, which is also what deployed yesterdays NuGet release. I also told you that [ServiceStack is under heavy development](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/P3ruPpFZezp) - you should not be looking to build from the source code which is highly volatile. The NuGet releases mark the **stable points** of the code-base (with all tests passing), all src and symbols are also deployed in NuGet packages, there shouldn't be a reason to use the repos.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict But it does seem that you're trying to rush into ServiceStack without taking the time to read the docs as your questions don't sound properly researched, so learning a new fx like ServiceStack is likely not be a good fit for you.

Comment: then why didn't it build the first time I pulled v3 down?

Comment: "you should not be looking to build from the source code which is highly volatile"  What do you mean source code, does that include v3's release?

Comment: "But it does seem that you're trying to rush into ServiceStack without taking the time to read the docs as your questions don't sound properly researched, so learning a new fx like ServiceStack is likely not be a good fit for you.".  Oh common dude...enough with the patriotism.   It's very simple, you pull down a branch, it should build.  What docs do you need to be able to do this.  What your docs don't talk about is what the heck is going on on your site as a whole, what builds, what has CI, what you shouldn't touch (volatile), etc.  Listen to your customers and stop making excuses.  Listen.

Comment: I still want to know why when I pulled the v3 branch a week ago, it didn't build.  There's not that much room for error on a consumer's end.  You download the build, open the solution and press Ctrl + Shift + B.  So how are you saying I don't know wtf I'm doing?  And then a week later I pull it down again just for kicks and it builds (something was fixed).  So if you have CI in place, why is that happening and where are the CI build errors?

Comment: "The NuGet releases mark the stable points of the code-base ".  The whole point of consuming SS is to consume your source code, not dlls.  At least in our case it is...which is usually the whole point of publishing an API right?

Comment: what I want from you is this defensive attitude and excuses and admit the site needs to be cleaned up and your CIs to work.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict CI's are working, you seem to fail to understand NuGet's are built and deployed from CI. Sorry, but ServiceStack's development practices does not revolve around you - like I said multiple times now, SS has been in heavy development for several weeks as we're in a major transition from `v3` -> `v4`. I'm not adding additional overhead to support anyone wanting to build from a volatile codebase. I think its time for you to move on, you've been the most taxing and time consuming person to support in history, it's clearly not in anyones interest to waste any more of each others time.

Comment: so you are basically saying to anyone coming to your API, do not use our API, everything is volatile right now?  There is no solid build I can use that your consumers have been using for v3?  I don't understand.

Comment: maybe the reason I've been the most to support is because you have not stated up front on your entire site for this time period that everything on that site is volatile until I forced the issue and you stated that is the case?  I just happened to try to use your API when EVERYTHING was volatile and that's my fault? I'm trying hard to understand how you think I'm the cause of the issues here.  Why are you not putting a Disclaimer such as "Hey guess what we are making volatile changes to EVERY branch you see on this site, even v3 which is technically a release that is to be stable?"

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Repos are an active working tree, don't expect anyone ever to put up a disclaimer every-time they make a commit. If you want a stable build, use the published releases - that's exactly what they're there for. But not anymore, use something else.

Comment: I did use the published release.  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/releases did not build....which has been my entire frustration.  It's been touched and changed too as you can see in the past month.  So that's why I'm saying there is no sense of release here where you know it's been frozen AND builds...that so that anyone can have confidence on using.  I'm not trying to waste your time, I'm frustrated and the problem is clear, nothing builds, and docs are all over as well as basic information is missing (what each branch is for, etc. which you finally answered in another post).

Comment: I am updating this post..stay tuned.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I meant the official NuGet releases, the `v3-snapshot` is an archive of `master` snapshot before `v3` was forked, and you just made me download it and build it myself - and it does build. Stop wasting my time.

Comment: check my new update.  What do you mean by official Nuget releases, where are they?  And it did NOT build for me, v3-snapshot.  See the updated post.  I will waste your time until you help your api customer...ME get a decent build going which again is not working on your site.  Is this too much to ask?  That you have a build that works?  That we know wtf is going on with branches and which release is what and what should work that does not?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict they are on the home page and every project home page as the official way to **Install** or **Download** ServiceStack.

Comment: ok you can NuGet the dlls only, not code.  I am trying to get a release of CODE.  So a repo # that you deem a release.  One that you say is what works.

Comment: and I have yet to get an answer from mythz on if really SS is meant for only using the published dlls as we can't trust the exposed source at any given time.